# Unity: Native Plugin is not found in standalone build on other computers

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, mono

I have compiled and imported the GameNetworkingSockets library into the unity Plugins folder. When doing a standalone build on my pc and running it, everything works fine, but when running the build on another pc, the dll files are not found. I have confirmed that the dll libraries are included in the builds Data/plugins folder.

```
    internal static class Native
    {
        private const string nativeLibrary = "GameNetworkingSockets";

        [DllImport(nativeLibrary, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern bool GameNetworkingSockets_Init(IntPtr identity, StringBuilder errorMessage);

    }
```

- I have tried moving the dlls into the root folder next  to the executable
- I have tried changing the minimal api to .net framework
- The native Plugins are in the Plugins folder

Also, which is kind of wierd, the set resolution for the game (windowed) is not used on other computers. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Far shot into the dark but maybe some 32bit vs 64bit issue?

Comment: Thanks for your response, i could try to compile a 32bit version and see if it works, but why would the game run in 32bit on another modern maschine? Could the unity editor have copied these dlls somewhere into my system files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was, that the used library needs some other dependencies to run, which where not present on the target system. For example the 140Runtime dll. I found this out, by using the dependency walker application.